# Paging for Listview inside a Gridview not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, listview, paging

I have a listview nested inside a gridview.

I'm trying to get paging working on the listview.  I thought that it would display the paging controls, and just page through them normally.

It does display the controls, and limits the result set shown to the appropriate number of records (pageSize) but when I click on the paging controls the grid refreshes and nothing changes with the nested listview (it's still on the first page).

I've tried nesting the listview inside an updatepanel, but the behavior remains.  The gridview itself is already in an updatepanel.

So this is the layout I've got:

```
<Gridview ID="gvApplications" DataSourceID="odsApplications" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Functions">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:ListView ID="lvFunctions" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("ApplicationFunctions") %>'
                      DataKeyNames="ID">
                     <LayoutTemplate>
                         <asp:DataPager ID="dpFunctions" runat="server" PageSize="1" PagedControlID="lvFunctions">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField />
                            </Fields>
                         </asp:DataPager>
                         <ul>
                         <li>
                            <span ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                         </li>
                         </ul>
                     </LayoutTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFunction" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApplicationFunction.Name") %>' />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:ListView>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</Gridview>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a ListView inside a GridView? Can you explain the nature of the application and what it is you are trying to display? :-)

Comment: I am trying to display a list of "child objects" related to the object in the gridview row.

Comment: I can get the list to show no problem.  The issue is that in some records there could be a large number of child objects, so I wanted it to page so it wouldn't warp the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would consider using a master-details pattern here. There are a lot of code examples on this. For example:

[Google: Master Details Examples with Child Objects](http://www.google.com/search?q=gridview+master-details&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=hwB&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=gridview+master-details+child+objects&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=4e781b66e30e329a)

There are also scenarios where the details view (child objects in your case) would display on a separate page. Either way, by displaying the child objects in a separate details view, you avoid the coding and display issues that come with nesting.

Matt Berseth has some of the best code examples out there on this topic:

http://mattberseth.com/blog/gridview/

Answer (score 0):

Listview / datapager combination do not work properly if the listview does not use a datasource control.

Try including a datasource control (objectdatasource could be applicable) in the template field.